# How to stop 'require_relative' requiring itself?

Tags: ruby, directory, require

In my Ruby without Rails application, I have a bunch of methods saved in various files, like methods.rb, other_methods.rb etc, that I want to access from my main file, main.rb.

Rather than spell out each 'require_relative' individually, my main.rb file currently reads:

```
main.rb

Dir["./*.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }
puts "executing"
```

The only problem is this outputs:

```
 "executing"
 "executing"
```

My current hacky approach is:

```
Dir["./*.rb"].each {|file| next if file == "./main.rb"; require file }
```

Is there a better way?

Should I be wrapping my methods in a Module, or a Mixin instead and then using 'include'?

Comment: how about separating the files you need to require in a folder? Then you can do `Dir["./methods/*.rb"].each(&method(:require_relative))`

Comment: Typically you'll want to put your supporting files in a `lib` folder as opposed to keeping everything in the same folder. I do this even for projects with a few supporting files. I suggest finding a gem or two that you like and look at the source code paying close attention to the folder structure.

Comment: I'm moving away from this sort of thing -- I actually LIKE the idea of naming all those files separately, for clarity and safety.  I guess you could go with `Dir["./*.rb"].reject{|x| x == "./main.rb"}.each{|y| require_relative y}`, which is a bit more expressive, at least.

Comment: @Finks +1 for the neat one-liner.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell so far my methods are dealing with videos, directories, downloads and string-matching. Should I be putting them in separate modules or mixins or something else, or is just putting all methods together in a lib folder just as good ? Am keen to start coding the 'Ruby way' as much as possible.